# Matlab tall arrays and memory

Tags: arrays, matlab, memory

The problem I'm having can be reproduced by running the code below.

```
gcp;
C={};
for i=1:1000
    C = [C,{tall(ones(1000,1,1000,2))}];
    pause(0.05)
end
```

My expectation is that, because tall arrays are only brought into memory for the purpose of evaluating expressions, and then only a few rows at a time, the above would not cause immediate memory problems. However, it seems to fill up my ram in exactly the same way as calling

```
gcp;
C={};
for i=1:1000
    C = [C,{ones(1000,1,1000,2)}];
    pause(0.05)
end
```

That is, using tall arrays does not seem to have any impact on memory usage at all.

If I wish to store large arrays of data produced by MatLab outside of memory, how should I do it? Using tall arrays doesn't seem to work.

Note: I am using MatLab 2017a, which doesn't support vertical concatenation of tall arrays. As such I am using the structure

```
{rows1,rows2,...,rowsn}
```

to represent blocks of rows of the same array. This may not be optimal.

Comment: From the [docs](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/tall-arrays.html): *Tall arrays provide a way to work with data backed by a datastore*. Only parts of the array are loaded into memory if the rest of the array is stored on disk elsewhere. Otherwise memory is the only place you've defined these arrays, how else can MATLAB hold onto what the array contains?

Comment: Oh, ok, I assumed it put it on disk somewhere out of the way, in one of its own directories. So I need to store each of my tall arrays to disk somewhere and then the memory will be free :)

Comment: Yes, that should work as you expect. You can programmatically save large arrays to disk of course, clearing memory as you go, then load them in collectively as a tall array.

Comment: How would I go about doing that? I understand that I can use save or write to store arrays to disk, but then how would I load them all in as a single array?

Comment: See [`datastore`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datastore.html) and [`gather`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/gather.html). You usually create a `datastore`, then create a `tall` array from that, perform (or rather define) operations on it, and then call `gather` to actually carry out the computations

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments - the local `tall` array constructor (where you give it local data rather than a `datastore`) is generally used only for in-memory prototyping before you point your `tall` arrays at your real large data in a `datastore`.

You can use [`tall/write`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/write.html) to write out your tall arrays to disk, then make a `datastore` reading in from the locations you used in `write`. This will process the data without loading it all back into memory at once.